# structtag go package seems not change tags inside function

Tags: json, go, go-structtag

im working to this code:

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "reflect"

        "github.com/fatih/structtag"
    )

    type Person struct {
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        Age     int    `json:"age"`
        Address string `json:"address"`
    }

    func main() {
        p := &Person{
            Name:    "John",
            Age:     30,
            Address: "123 Main St",
        }
        p.setTag("Name","newtag")
        p.read1Tag ("Name")
    }

    func (p* Person) setTag(fieldName string,tagValue string){
        field, _ := reflect.TypeOf(*p).FieldByName(fieldName)
        tags, _ := structtag.Parse(string(field.Tag))
        tags.Delete("json")
        tag := &structtag.Tag{
            Key:  "json",
            Name: tagValue,
        }
        tags.Set(tag)
        field.Tag = reflect.StructTag(tags.String())
        tag1, _ := tags.Get("json")
        fmt.Println (tag1)
        field.Tag = reflect.StructTag(tags.String())
        }



    func (p Person) read1Tag (fieldName string) {
        field, _ := reflect.TypeOf(p).FieldByName(fieldName)
        tags, _ := structtag.Parse(string(field.Tag))
        tag, _ := tags.Get("json")
        fmt.Println (tag)
    }
```

I want to modify a json tag for the struct Person , field Name. The code , modify the tags inside the setTaG() function, but when i try to read it from main i have the old tag ( i have println the tag inside both the function ).  I have defined the handler by reference, could someone help me , to mantain the tag out of the function? thanks.

i have try to run the code , and i would like to mantain the modified tag out of the setTag() ; so when i reread it , i would like to see the new value for the tag.

Comment: You cannot modify the struct tags of a struct type at runtime. This is simply _not possible_.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the tags of `p` with that library and I wouldn't recommend trying it. `structtag.Tag` has no relation to the original `struct` - you pass a tag `string` to be parsed, which could come from anywhere as far as`structtag` is concerned.

So, what you have to do instead: create a method like

```golang
func (p Person) getAdjustedTags() (adjustedTags structtag.Tags)
```

where you parse the tags from the `Person`, modify thoses parsed tags and return them (as `adjustedTags`). Use these `adjustedTags` for your further logic and pass them if need be.

You could even go a step further and just create a method like

```golang
func getAdjustedTags(withTags any) (adjustedTags structtag.Tags)
```

to support that for any struct with tags, since it has no relation to `Person` anyway.

Comment: thanks. but i need to modify the Person's tag at runtime, it is possible in this way? could you give a little example? thanks  a lot (im newer in golang).

Comment: @CastracucchiDavide As mkopriva has pointed out, you can't do it. You've defined the `struct` tag on compile time. It's fixed. What you can do instead: gather all tag information from the `struct` (here: the `Person), modify those information if requred and pass them around. You claimed that you need to modify the `Person`s tag, but it's not possible and there _are_ other options. I can'r really provide more examples if I don't know your use case. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem @CastracucchiDavide. The solution you've chosen is _not possible_ to implement, not in Go. Perhaps you would have more luck if you edit your question to instead ask about the problem you are trying to solve with this non-workable, modify-tags-at-runtime "solution".